# how to make the mysql master to only do writes and slaves do the read

Tags: mysql, database, master-slave

I am trying to setup MySQL master slave network. Application is ready heavy and not write heavy. How to configure the master to do only writes and slaves to do only the read operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it automatically with MySQL, you have to do it on a per query basis. One way is create 2 DB connections, one for reads and one for writes, and make sure you use the correct one for each query.

I wrote a PHP DB abstraction class ([available on github](https://github.com/shutterstock/basecoat/wiki/Database)) that handles this automatically. You instantiate the class telling it which server is the master and which is the slave (any number of slaves). It then automatically sends INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs over the master connection and SELECTs over the slave connection. It does this by having a function for each type of query, and supports overriding default behavior (i.e. SELECT from master).

It's part of the [Basecoat](https://github.com/shutterstock/basecoat) framework, but it's not dependent on the framework in any way so you can use it independently, if you are using PHP. It also handles escaping, on-demand connections, connection recovery, profiling, multi-inserts, etc. It is not an ORM though.

Comment: so what about data consistency? you read stale info from replica, apply some logic and write new value to master. the outcome can be different were you to only read/write from master.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while ago by running a regular expression on each SQL statement. If it's a SELECT, the database library would connect to the slave, otherwise to the master. If there was a write operation (INSERT, UPDATE etc.), all subsequent SELECTs in the same hit went to the master as well, because there could be delays between master and slave. (There are a few subtleties in detecting whether a given SQL command is read or write, e.g. SELECT INTO or stored procedures, but you don't need to be exact. When in doubt use the master.)

This is not very sophisticated, but in my scenario it worked very well and was easy to set up without additional hard- or software.